# What is the formal way to ask whether they have received my E-mail?

Tags: letter

I wrote an email im German to someone but still haven’t received a reply. What is an appropriate way to write them again and asking whether they have received it or not?

Comment: We need more information. Would you like to sound angry? Have you a more formal or a more familiar relationship? Have you a relationship at all, former Mail exchange?

Answer (score 1):

The formal way would look like this:

"Sehr geehrte/r (geehrte if female, geehrter male) Frau(female)/Herr(male) {their last name},

haben Sie die Mail, die ich Ihnen gesendet habe, erhalten?

Mit freundlichen Grüßen

{Your Name}
"

Comment: Das "... habe zukommen lassen" klingt für mich sehr gestelzt. Ein "... die Ich Ihnen geschickt habe, erhalten?" sehr viel weniger feierlich, und daher in den meisten Fällen besser angepasst. Es gibt, zweifelsohne, auch Fälle in denen es feierlich klingen soll. Normal schickt oder schreibt man Mails, und gut. Gut vielleicht noch das Datum zu nennen, falls der Mailclient die Mails chronologisch sortiert: "... die Ich Ihnen am letzten Freitag, den 22., geschickt habe, erhalten?"

Comment: Das Wort "ich" soll mit einem kleinen "i" geschrieben werden. Auf englisch wird "I" immer groß geschrieben.

Comment: Richtig, war Auto korrekt :/